# How can I get multiple x axis values in dygraphs

Tags: dygraphs

Is it possible in dygraphs to display multiple x axis or to display multiple x axis labels if there are for example two data sets loaded with different x axis values (other time periods) and I want to display them both on the x axis?

Trying to compare two sets of data for different periods and I would like both periods to be shown on the x axis.

Or is there a way to extract the date ranges somewhere and hardcode the extra values/x-axis myself?

Cheers,
Marc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no built-in support for multiple independent x-axes in dygraphs. The closest you can come is something like the [independent series](http://dygraphs.com/tests/independent-series.html) demo, which shows how you can combine multiple series with independent x-axes into one chart.

Comment: That's what I figured after reading the docs. I've got multiple data series and need to compare them. I've got everything working just fine, and on hover the series show the correct (different) dates in a tooltip. Guess i'll manually add something to get the functionality I need.